# Divide array into subarray

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to create two sub-arrays from this array:

```
 a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This array will not always contain the same number  of elements because  it depends on the user input.

For example, in some occasions it'll be:

```
a = [0, 5]
```

or:

```
a = [5, 6, 4]
```

I want to divide the array into two subarrays. The first one will contain numbers from 1 to 4 (inclusive) and the second one will contain 0, 5 and 6.

In the first example, it will be:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
sub_array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sub_array2 = [0, 5, 6]
```

In the second:

```
a = [0, 5] 
sub_array1 = []
sub_array2 = [5]
```

In the third:

```
a = [5, 6, 4]
sub_array1 = [4]
sub_array2 = [5, 6]
```

and so on, depending on the user input.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition).

```
sub_array1, sub_array2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6].partition {|x| (1..4).include? x }
=> [[1,2,3,4], [0,5,6]]
```

if you have two conditions (I mean if 0,5,6 are an actual condition and not the excluded set) I think that a double iteration wouldn't hurt

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
sub_array1 = a.select { |x| (1..4).include? x }
sub_array2 = a.select { |x| [0,5,6].include? x }
```

Comment: Yep! This works! Basically, because later I need to determine the lenght of each subarray. Thanks!

Comment: Mr. X, I think you can improve your (good) answer by prepending `sub_array1, sub_array_2 =` and deleting "but" and all that follows. Also, small typo: you forgot the zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].group_by{|x| [0,5,6].include? x}
```

The result will be a hash:

```
{true=>[0, 5, 6], false=>[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

In the second case:

```
[0,5].group_by{|x| [0,5,6].include? x}
```

The result will be:

```
{true=>[0, 5]}
```

Comment: This is lovely.. but I don't think it suits my case.

Comment: I believe you can meet the OP's objection by tacking on `.values` and prepending with `arr1, arr2 =`.