# Divide one array into two nested array

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing 4 values. I need to make it a nested array with two arrays containing two values. Javascript is needed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055578/divide-array-into-subarray) could help but it is in Ruby. [Array reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572605/divide-array-into-multiple-arrays) may help but I am not able to use it well enough.

```
array = [20, 45, 22, 51]
result = [[20,45],[22,51]]
```

Comment: (as well as many more [Split array into chunks of N length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318680/split-array-into-chunks-of-n-length), [How to split a long array into smaller arrays, with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273668/how-to-split-a-long-array-into-smaller-arrays-with-javascript) etc. etc.)

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `slice`

```js
const array = [20, 45, 22, 51]

const mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2);

const result = [[0, mid], [mid, array.length]].map(idxs => array.slice(...idxs))

console.log(result)
```